# Can these two SQL queries be combined?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if there's a way I can combine these two queries into one? I need to get the mean and std dev for each column in the `company_feature` table. I then need to take those two values and use them in an aggregation query on each row in the `company_feature` table.

```
/* Get mean and std dev for each feature column */
SELECT 
    AVG(F1) AS F1_mean, 
    STDDEV(F1) AS F1_std_dev
FROM company_feature_test cft;
```

```
/* Add averages for each feature to the following query */
SELECT
    DATA.company_id,
      (
       CASE
         WHEN DATA.in_ref_set = 0 AND DATA.size = 'SMALL'
         THEN 
           1 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - :F1_mean) / :F1_std_dev ) * 1
         WHEN DATA.in_ref_set = 0 AND DATA.size = 'MEDIUM'
         THEN 
           2 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - :F1_mean) / :F1_std_dev ) * 2           
         WHEN DATA.in_ref_set = 0 AND DATA.size = 'LARGE'
         THEN 
           3 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - :F1_mean) / :F1_std_dev ) * 3   
         WHEN DATA.in_ref_set = 0 AND DATA.size = 'VERY_LARGE'
         THEN 
           4 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - :F1_mean) / :F1_std_dev ) * 4
         ELSE
           5 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - :F1_mean) / :F1_std_dev )
       END
      ) AS feature_1
FROM (
  SELECT company.in_ref_set, company.size, cft.*
  FROM company_feature_test cft
  JOIN company ON company.id = cft.company_id
  GROUP BY company.id
) AS DATA
GROUP BY DATA.company_id;
```

the tables look like the following (below). There is a relation between company.id and company_feature.company_id.

```
company table

| id | ref_set | size |
| -- | --- | --- |
| 1  | 0   | SMALL |
| 2  | 1   | LARGE |


company_feature table

| company_id | F1 | F2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 5   | 10  |
| 2   | 15  | 20  |
```

The query outputs the following data:

```
| company_id | feature_1 |
| --- | --- | 
| 1   | -1.66 |
| 2   | -1.44 |
```

Comment: What is wrong with two separate queries?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is a followon question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216603, see there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just cross join them:

```
SELECT
    DATA.company_id,
      (
       CASE
         WHEN DATA.in_ref_set = 0 AND DATA.size = 'SMALL'
         THEN 
           1 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - TOTALS.F1_mean) / TOTALS.F1_std_dev ) * 1
         WHEN DATA.in_ref_set = 0 AND DATA.size = 'MEDIUM'
         THEN 
           2 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - TOTALS.F1_mean) / TOTALS.F1_std_dev ) * 2           
         WHEN DATA.in_ref_set = 0 AND DATA.size = 'LARGE'
         THEN 
           3 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - TOTALS.F1_mean) / TOTALS.F1_std_dev ) * 3   
         WHEN DATA.in_ref_set = 0 AND DATA.size = 'VERY_LARGE'
         THEN 
           4 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - TOTALS.F1_mean) / TOTALS.F1_std_dev ) * 4
         ELSE
           5 * ((LN(DATA.F1 + 1) - TOTALS.F1_mean) / TOTALS.F1_std_dev )
       END
      ) AS feature_1
FROM (
  SELECT company.in_ref_set, company.size, cft.*
  FROM company_feature_test cft
  JOIN company ON company.id = cft.company_id
  GROUP BY company.id
) AS DATA
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 
    AVG(F1) AS F1_mean, 
    STDDEV(F1) AS F1_std_dev
  FROM company_feature_test cft
) AS TOTALS
```

Note that there's no need to group by in the outer query; there will already only be one row per company.

Note that you still seem to be doing conditional aggregation incorrectly, if that is what you are trying to do; assuming there are multiple rows in cft for each company, you will be selecting an *arbitrary* F1 for each company.  Default settings in newer versions of mysql will prohibit this.

Comment: This doesn't really improve performance much, but it does make the query harder to read.

Comment: a CTE would be clearer, but I don't find this that hard to read.  it's cross joining a multiple row subquery to a single row subquery, and pretty straightforward.

Comment: Using MySQL 5 - doesn't support CTEs unfortunately. Otherwise I agree a CTE would be ideal.

Comment: re performance, if you do two separate queries, then you have issues with the data changing between them.  though even here, the totals subquery includes rows with companies that are not found in the company table that the data subquery excludes.

Comment: people almost never say "mysql 5", there were such dramatic differences between each point release you should always say 5.7 or 5.6 or whatever.  though all but 5.7 are now past end of life and no longer secure (as will be 5.7 later this year)